# Инициализация Java Fx

Tags: java, javafx

Использую Java FX, пытаюсь создать небольшое приложение с парой контроллеров и представлений с помощью Spring boot. На сколько знаю что бы использовать все плюшки DI Spring нужно правильно разделить инициализацию Spring и Java FX, поскольку сначала надо пройти инициализацию Java FX, и только после этого вся польза спринга будет доступна(в моем случае DI сервисов и контроллеров). Есть класс:

```
@Component
public class TableController {

    @FXML private TableView<File> table;
    @Autowired private Service service;

    private ObservableList observableList;
    private List<File> ioList;

    public TableController() {}

    public File getSelectedItem() {
        return table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize(){
        System.out.println("JavaFx init");
        TableColumn<File, String> name = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        TableColumn<File, String> file = new TableColumn<>("File");;
        TableColumn<File, String> extension = new TableColumn<>("Extension");;
        name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<File, String>("name"));
        file.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<File, String>("file"));
        extension.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<File, String>("extension "));

        table.getColumns().setAll(name, singer, extension);
    }

    @PostConstruct
public void init(){
    ioList = service.getAll();
    observableList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    observableList.setAll(ioList);
}

    public void showItems() {
        table.setItems(observableList);
    }
}
```

метод `showItems()` вызывается в главном классе, наследнике `Application`, в методе `start()`, так вот в этот момент переменная table не проинициализирована, хотя вызов метода `initialize()` проходит нормально и там переменная проинициализирована, но при вызове `showItems()` я ловлю NPE. В чем промах?

Файл fxml этого контроллера:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="434.0" prefWidth="350.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="view.controller.TableController ">
    <children>
        <TableView prefHeight="434.0" prefWidth="350.0" fx:id="songs">
        </TableView>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

**UPD**
Как подсказал @notaProgrammer проблема в том что создается отдельные два экземпляра класса: JavaFX создает один Spring - другой. Суть вопроса не поменялась: какие есть варианты "подружить" Spring и JavaFX, что бы Spring пользовал тот класс который создает JavaFX?

Comment: Могу предположить, что создаётся 2 экземпляра класса TableController: созданный JavaFX и Spring

Comment: @notaProgrammer да, вы правы. А вообще используют Spring в паре с JavaFX и если да, то как обходят проблему?

Comment: @Dmitriy Kruglov Spring используют, но есть два лагеря за и против. У вас не приведен код, в котором FX и spring создают экземпляры контроллера.

Comment: К сожалению, не могу подсказать. С JavaFX работал давно и Spring до этого не знал.

Answer (score 0):

У FXMLLoader есть такой метод:

```
javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.setControllerFactory(Callback<Class<?>, Object>)
```

который позволяет переопределить каким образом будут создаваться экземпляры контроллеров. Нужно реализовать этот Callback, в котором будут возвращаться бины из спрингового контекста и JavaFX будет использовать их.